# How To increase the number of connections in mysql community edition?

Tags: mysql, connection

MySQL by default is letting me have 151 simultaneous connections. 
It let me increase it through MAX ALLOWED CONNECTIONS option in the Workbench.

When I have increased the count to 1000, it is not getting reflected.
The Server Status page shows that the Maximum Allowed Client connection is still set to 300.

Why is that ?

Is there a way that I can increase this count for say 10000 or even 1,00,000 ?

I have MySQL Server installation on Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to set:
1. set GLOBAL max_connections=XXX in command line 
2. add max_connections=XXX in my.ini file and restart mysql
Max connection limit is 100000 in my Win7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

To set it: SET max_connections=10000
To verify it: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'

However, before setting this variable pls make sure you read [How Mysql opens and closes tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-cache.html) section of mysql documentation to understand the implications and posdible limits your OS imposes!